# Solidity contract functions not returning correctly with Truffle, but working on Remix

Tags: solidity, truffle, remix, javascript, truffle-contract

I'm testing my contracts using Truffle, but my functions are not returning the correct uint, despite doing so when testing in Remix. This is my Test.js code:

```
var EventContract = artifacts.require("./EventContract.sol");
contract ('EventContract', function (accounts){
it("account1 purchases 4 tickets from ticketContract, which had 10 tickets to start with at a cost of 2", function(){
    var event;
    var account1 = accounts[0];

    return EventContract.deployed()
    .then(function(instance){
      event = instance;
        return event.buyTicketsFromContract.call(account1, 2, {from: account1, value: 4});
    })
    .then (function (success){
      console.log("purchased from contract with success: " + success);
      assert.equal(true, success, "bought 2 tickets for 4 ether");
      return event.getContractTicketBalance.call();
    })
    .then (function(contractBalance){
      console.log(contractBalance.toNumber());
// Fails here
      assert.equal(8, contractBalance.toNumber(), "contract ticket balance is not 8");
      return event.getTicketBalance.call(account1);
    })
    .then (function(accountBalance){
      assert.equal(2, accountBalance.toNumber(), "account balance is not 2");
    })
    ;
  })
  ;
```

It fails because the contract ticket balance is 10 (initial amount), not 8. When using the same functions on Remix, the values returned are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop `.call()` from this line: `return event.buyTicketsFromContract.call(account1, 2, {from: account1, value: 4});`

When you say `call()`, you are explicitly saying this is a read-only request so don't even try to update the blockchain. Consequently, when you check what happened, you find that nothing happened.

Hope it helps.